# Why is $5^{25} \equiv 22 \mod 193$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to apply the square and multiply algorithm and I'm getting strange results even though I'm pretty sure I've done everything right. I'm trying to calculate $5^{25} \mod 193$:

Binary representation of 25: 11001

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
5^2 = 25 \\
25*5 = 125 \\
125^2 = 185 \\
185*5 = 153 \\
152^2 = 56 \\
56^2 = 48 \\
48^2 = 181 \\
181*5 = 133
\end{split}
\end{equation}

But when I check my answer on wolframalpha it tells me the correct solution should be 22. I checked every single step twice. What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you're computing $5^{57}$.

- start with $5^2$
- multiplying that by $5$ gives $5^3$
- squaring that gives $5^6$
- multiplying that by $5$ gives $5^7$
- squaring that gives $5^{14}$
- squaring that gives $5^{28}$
- squaring that gives $5^{56}$
- multiplying that by $5$ gives $5^{57}$

Comment: You are right, but I'm following the definition of the algorithm. For every 1-coefficient I square and multiply and else I just square. What is wrong there?

Comment: @AdHominem You need to start with the value 1, not 5. I.e., you start with $1^2 = 1$, $1\cdot 5 = 5$ etc. Alternatively, you can start with the value 5, but then you skip the first binary digit, i.e., you only use the digits 1001, not 11001.

Comment: @Litho Damn you are right. Such a stupid mistake.